# Preg Replace remove text selected between same tag

Tags: php, regex

for example, i have this tag

```
<font color="#6f6f6f">hahahahahahahaha</font>
<font color="#6f6f6f">ABC DEFG</font>
<font size="-1" class="p">blablablababababaab</font>
```

how to remove `<font color="#6f6f6f">ABC DEFG</font>` with preg replace ?

i have tried, like this. but its remove all font tag

```
preg_replace('#(<font.*?>).*?(</font>)#', '', $desc);
```

Comment: @sshashank124, Because that is the requirement right ? ;) Please don't use regex for this. Use a DOM parser.

Comment: Why do you need a regex? `str_replace('<font size="-1" class="p">blablablababababaab</font>', '', $string);`.

Comment: @Chielarck, please explain CRITERIA for removing. What is difference between first font tag, and second one? Uppercase? Or, simple, that (ABC...) is SECOND font tag (on page/inside string)?

Comment: @sshashank124 how if without text ABC DEFG ? because the text can be changed . look at my update question

Comment: @nevermind i want remove in second font tag

Comment: Ok, now it is clear. Now you will get valuable answers, i am sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$desc='<font color="#6f6f6f">hahahahahahahaha</font>
<font color="#6f6f6f">ABC DEFG</font>
<font size="-1" class="p">blablablababababaab</font>';

preg_match_all('#<font.*?>.*?</font>#',$desc,$match);

unset($match[0][1]);

print_r($match);
```

And then just convert it to string, again (implode).

Answer (score 0):

i agree with amal str_replac is better

```
$string= '<font size="-1" class="p">blablablababababaab</font><font color="#6f6f6f">ABC DEFG</font>
<font size="-1" class="p">blablablababababaab</font>';

str_replace('<font size="-1" class="p">blablablababababaab</font>', '', $string);
```